# Add gesture for the imageView in tableView's Section Header

Tags: ios, swift, header, tableview, gesture

I want to implement a tableview with a header look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQFgZ.jpg). I want to implement a function that it segue to another view controller when i press the icon in this header.
But it seems the gesture recognizer doesn't work. The recognizer would give no response at all

The header's code is here

```
  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let headerView = UITableViewHeaderFooterView(frame:CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frameWidth, height: headerViewHeight))
        let iconOffset = CGPoint(x: 8, y: 8)
        let iconSize = CGSize(width: headerViewHeight-16, height: headerViewHeight-16)
        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(origin: iconOffset, size: iconSize))
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "HENRY")
        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = (headerViewHeight-16)/2
        imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true

        let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("iconTapGestureHandler:"))
//        tapRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        tapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        tapRecognizer.delegate = self
        imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)

        headerView.addSubview(imageView)
        return headerView
}
```

However, the iconTapGestureHandler function wouldn't be triggered after a tap the image view.

I have also implement the delegate method.

```
func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true
}
func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

the iconTapGestureHandler  Function is as below

```
@IBAction func iconTapGestureHandler(sender:UIGestureRecognizer){
    println("in touch")
    let mainPageVC = MainPageTableViewController()
    mainPageVC.isMyself = false
    mainPageVC.isPushed = false
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(mainPageVC, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default in UIImageView user interaction is disabled. So add

`imageView.userInteractionEnabled = true`

Comment: Thanks a lot. This solve the problem. The next problem is that i want to give it some properties before the mainPageVC is pushed into the navigation controller such as the touched userIcon. How to identify which  section is being touched? So that i can get the properties by section number.

Comment: You can add tag in viewForHeaderInSection: imageView.tag = section and get section in iconTapGestureHandler: let section = sender.view!.tag